# C Program works when run+built, but the .exe created will NOT run (library issue for sure)

Tags: c, curl, codeblocks

I'm using cURL and Code::Blocks. 
The libcurl.a and libcurldll.a are put in Code::Block's generic folder (\CodeBlocks\MinGW\lib). cURL is included with #include .

I've tried linking either libcurl.a, libcurldll.a, or both. Either or both make the program work when used with the build+run option, but the .exe in the \projectname\bin\debug folder crashes when it gets to the cURL bit in the code for any combination.

I used a generic cURL example code:
http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simple.html

I've asked several people about this, and they look at me weird. Additionally, web searches don't yield anything useful. I'm sure I'm just asking the wrong way.

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying the simple program crashes when you run it manually(for example, from a command shell) but it doesn't crash when ran from codeblock's 'build+run' option? And yes you are asking the wrong way -- you're not providing enough information and the way you described your problem is unclear which is evident given my first question.

Comment: it's most likely the paths for dynamic libraries.  It's set to one thing inside your IDE and something else when you run it from the command line.

Comment: Is the library used is for the same platform that of executable?

Comment: Building the program produces a .exe file. Build+Run let the program work, but going into the folder and double clicking the .exe file causes it to crash when it uses the cURL code, as I have text printed that announces the cURL code is about to run.

Build+Run also was required for Dev-C++, and I switched to Code::Blocks to try to get away from the .exe not running alone.

How do I "embed" the library? Linking to the libcurl.a/libcurldll.a both don't "stay" with the program once it leaves the initial build+run.

Not sure what IDE in this context is, nor what the question from akhil means.